# X-Amzn-Trace-Id not present in response header when response status is other than 200

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I am using X-Ray tracing in API Gateway and Lambda authorizer. Inside the authorizer, I am calling two HTTP URLs.

- When I give invalid URL for one http call, I am throwing callback ("unauthorized") from lambda authorizer. Hence, the response status will be 401. When I look into the response headers, I couldn't find X-Amzn-Trace-Id.
- When the URL is valid and status is 200, `X-Amzn-Trace-Id` is seen in response headers.

Is there anyway to retrieve `X-Amzn-Trace-Id` irrespective of the status (always)?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for delay in the response. We have raised this issue with API Gateway team and actively working with them to resolve this issue. I cannot provide any ETA at this point but please stay tuned. At the moment, there is no way to retrieve "X-Amzn-Trace-Id" irrespective of the status from the response. The "X-Amzn-Trace-Id" is populated by API Gateway segment and it seems missing for the above use case other than 200 status code.

Thanks for the patience.